# why my plugin don't traslate wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, po, mo

i'm doing a wordpress plugin.

my_plugin.php

```
/*
* Plugin Name: my plugin
* Author:      Vendetta
* Author URI:  http://abel-olguin.com
* Text Domain: my_plugin
* Domain Path: /languages
*/
```

*.po and *.mo files are in lenguages and i call traslate whit

```
__("text in po", "my_plugin")
```

files *.po and *.mo in directory languages names:

> my_plugin-en_US.po, my_plugin-es_ES.po...

but strings are not translated, always show everything in English and my browser is in spanish.
what it's wrong?

Comment: you have selected spanish in WordPress settings?

Comment: yep :'( i loose hope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to load your plugin’s translations files using the function [`load_plugin_textdomain()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/load_plugin_textdomain).

```
function my_plugin_load_plugin_textdomain() {
    load_plugin_textdomain( 'my-plugin', FALSE, basename( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . '/languages/' );
}
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'my_plugin_load_plugin_textdomain' );
```

Read more here: http://ottopress.com/tag/internationalization/